# I am trying to run a Python script in Flask that schedules a task at specific time intervals

Tags: python

I've looked through the documentation of these sites:
https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html
https://pypi.org/project/ischedule/#description

And I can't seem to figure out to do this.

```
def TESTING_TIMING():
    import schedule
    import time
    
    conn = db_connection.test_connection()
    
    # cursor = conn.cursor()
    schedule.every().day.do(FUNCTION_LOG_VOTER_DICT_WITH_FILE_ID_DICT, conn, "Daily") # TODO: ATTACH A LOG TO THIS
    schedule.every().month.do(FUNCTION_LOG_VOTER_DICT_WITH_FILE_ID_DICT, conn, "Monthly") # TODO: ATTACH A LOG TO THIS
    schedule.every().year.do(FUNCTION_LOG_VOTER_DICT_WITH_FILE_ID_DICT, conn, "Yearly") # TODO: ATTACH A LOG TO THIS
    
    while True:
        schedule.run_all()
```

Here is my code so far which absolutely doesn't work but I think these gives an idea of what I'm trying to do. I can't do this in task scheduler unfortunately because the Flask is running inside of a docker container, so it has to be local to the scrips, any ideas on how I should go about this?

Comment: I usually would use `dagster` or `airflow` to performed scheduled tasks as they give all necessary goodies, monitoring, logics, retries etc

Comment: Have you tried forcing it to run only at a specified time during the day so it only runs once daily? Similarly, for the monthly option have that run only on a consistent day of the month such as the 1st of the month. And for yearly have it run only on a particular day of the month on a specified month.

Comment: @JimRogers Yeah I can get something hacked together to make it run at a particular time of day but I haven't figured out how to do that for the month, let alone for the year

Comment: @PraysonW.Daniel Okay I will look into those libraries and get back to you in a bit